# changing width of a div with random class name

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

i want to change the width of Facebook comment plugin from 620px to 100% to make it responsive. everything works fine but there is a div which has width of 620px and it gets random id name on every refresh of the page, and that is why i can't target the class. it will be great if anyone know how can i target this specific class.

here is the some part of html code.

```
<body dir="ltr" class="plugin webkit chrome win x1 Locale_en_US">
   <div class="_li"><div class="pluginSkinLight pluginFontHelvetica">
     <div id="feedback_1Is4cWupeqo2ATYOW" style="width: 620px;">
        <div class="fbFeedbackContent" id="u_0_1">
          <div class="stat_elem">
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

the div with id="feedback_1Is4cWupeqo2ATYOW" change every time. how can i target this specific div in css.

here is the link for demo, try to change the width of 620px to some other value. http://nowgags.comuf.com/?p=1

Answer (score 0):

Could try this

```
div.pluginSkinLight > div {
width: 400px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.plugin div[id^="feedback_"]{
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

selects where id start with feedback_

Comment: That will select all `div`'s under `pluginSkinLight`.

Comment: Edit: will target div with that width specifically. Not ideal but will find the right one.

Comment: @Dhunt Will it now? You should show a working demo. I think you find that will not work.

Comment: Sorry - pasted it in wrong. whats there now seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/h10L6uas/1/

Comment: tried both but still not working, don't know why. everything looks normal.

Answer (score 0):

Using pseudo classes:

```
.pluginSkinLight div:first-child {
  ...
}
```

Comment: i have tried this already. it works fine when i use it in inspect elements, but when i refresh the page then boom, styling disappear from the targeted div.

Comment: Put it into the stylesheets. Developer tools will always reset to original CSS when you refresh the page.

Comment: i am putting it in stylesheet. .pluginSkinLight div:first-child { work in deveopler tool but not in ctylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the html structure and classes don't change (except for the feedback id) - this should work

```
.pluginSkinLight.pluginFontHelvetica > div {
   width: 100% !important; 
}
```

Here we use the [child combinator selector](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/child) '>' to only select direct descendants of an element's parent

See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/m7f5s9uw/) (use inspect element to see that the feedback div gets 100% width)

Comment: pluginSkinLight.pluginFontHelvetica don't change but the styling doesn't work.

Comment: @AbuBakar - check the demo I posted

Comment: i know it works, but not in my case. i don't know why. here is the link to fb comment plugin demo. inpsect it what is restoring the width of 620px. it is just a demo because my content width is now 500px, and in demo it is 620px. http://nowgags.comuf.com/?p=1